# Sort Array by Popularity and Time in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am a Ruby Rails newbie.

Is there a way to know the popularity of elements in an Array over time?

For example lets say for the last 15 min..

The array has like ["abc", "ab", "abc", "a", "abc", "ab"........] being pushed into the array.. can we get "abc" and "ab" as the most popular ones.. just for the last 15 minutes?

If you take for an entire hour.. typical for the entire hour.."abcd" is the most popular.. it should return "abcd" as the most popular element in an array..

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Arrays doesn't contain any information on when an element was added

Comment: Agreed. If I saved this to database. Is there a way to achieve this functionality? Thanks!

Comment: Yes but then it becomes a database problem. Group by, order by, where created_at<15.minutes.ago you get the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own class which inherits from Array, or delegates all its functionality to an Array. For example:

```
class TimestampedArray
  def initialize
    @items = []
  end

  def <<(obj)
    @items << [Time.now,obj]
  end

  # get all the items which were added in the last "seconds" seconds
  # assumes that items are kept in order of add time
  def all_from_last(seconds)
    go_back_to = Time.now - seconds
    result     = []
    @items.reverse_each do |(time,item)|
      break if time < go_back_to
      result.unshift(item)
    end
    result
  end
end
```

If you have an old version of Ruby, which doesn't have `reverse_each`:

```
def all_from_last(seconds)
  go_back_to = Time.now - seconds
  result     = []
  (@items.length-1).downto(0) do |i|
    time,item = @items[i]
    break if time < go_back_to
    result.unshift(item)
  end
  result
end
```

Then you need something to find the "most popular" item. I often use this utility function:

```
module Enumerable
  def to_histogram
    result = Hash.new(0)
    each { |x| result[x] += 1 }
    result
  end
end
```

On which you could base:

```
module Enumerable
  def most_popular
    h = self.to_histogram
    max_by { |x| h[x] }
  end
end
```

So then you get:

```
timestamped_array.all_from_last(3600).most_popular # "most popular" in last 1 hour
```

Comment: thanks for the reply Alex! I have an issue.. it says NoMethodError in Tweets#index

Showing /Users/gkolan/work/basicblog/app/views/tweets/index.html.erb where line #15 raised:

undefined method `reverse_each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Alex.. I am very new to Rails! Should I create a helper class called module Enumerable like Tweets Helper rb file in module TweetsHelper and then say include Enumerable in my Tweets Model? I am so confused :(

Comment: @reko, open a command prompt and type `ruby -v`. I am running Ruby 1.9.2p290. I suspect you have an older version of ruby, which doesn't have `reverse_each`.

Comment: I just posted code which you can use if you don't have `reverse_each`. `Enumerable` is a core Ruby module, and this code is just extending it. I suggest you create a file called `core_extensions.rb`, put the `Enumerable` code in there, and put it in config/initializers/. Then you can put `TimestampedArray` in a file called `timestamped_array.rb` and put that in lib/.